# Visual Studio specify definition file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsd

I am using the [typescript definition manager](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/) to manage TypeScript definitions for a project I'm developing in Visual Studio 2015.

It creates a "tsd.d.ts" file that references all type def files installed with tsd.  This is great because just this can be referenceed in TypeScript files rather than many, many type definition files.

However, it would be great if even this was not necessary.  Is there any way to tell Visual Studio about this file so I don't have to put a a reference path like this at the top of every TypeScript file? -

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

I think I can reference it in the tsconfig.json file for compilation, but things still break at design time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `.d.ts` file to your project with `TypeScriptCompile` build action:

[image: TypeScriptCompile build action]

After that just remove all reference comments, all works without them.

Also you can search for typings without TSD just from Solution Explorer menu:

[image: Search for typings]